# Create 'subfolders' in Artifactory Maven repository

Tags: deployment, maven-2, artifactory, snapshot

My team wants to separate our snapshots by which environment they should deploy to. We have a Development, Stage, and Test environment. We have a Maven Repository called BASE. I would like to deploy our snapshots to BASE/Develop, BASE/Stage, etc

How can I create a repository path like this? When I try to set the `mvn deploy -DaltSnapshotDeploymentRepository=repoID::default::https://artifactory/BASE/Develop` I get an error `Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict.`
If I remove the `Develop`, it works fine.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The common practice for that in Artifactory is using different local repositories for different lifecycle states. Then use build promotion in order to move your artifacts through the lifecycle states. Use a virtual repository, aggregating the other repositories, in order to use a single source to resolve your dependencies.

For more details and examples, see:

- [Onboarding Best Practices: JFrog Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Onboarding+Best+Practices%3A+JFrog+Artifactory)
- Knowledge Base: [How Does Build Promotion work](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-does-build-promotion-work/)
- White Paper - [Best Practices for Structuring and Naming Artifactory Repositories](https://jfrog.com/whitepaper/best-practices-structuring-naming-artifactory-repositories/)
- Documentation on [Maven repositories](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Maven+Repository) in Artifactory

Comment: I will look into this! I'm still very interested in knowing if my folder structure question is possible.

Comment: See the links below as an example. It shows a solution to add a sub-directory, based on the current git branch, implemented as a maven plugin.
https://www.mattshelton.net/2015/11/17/creative-branching-models-for-multiple-release-streams/
https://bitbucket.org/mattshelton/maven-branch-extension/src/master/

But it's not a standard way, nor an easy way.

Comment: Forgot to mention, regarding the use of sub-directories - you will also need to define a custom layout in Artifactory and assign it to your repository. See: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Layouts